# How do I modify my code to store totals to my decArray?

Tags: c#

I am frustrated. I'm a newbie doing my homework I cannot seem to figure out why my messagebox just shows the same number(last subtotal number calculated) five times. I'm not understanding how to use the for loop to store my values into the array without it resetting. Would anybody be able to help? Thank you in advance.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace InvoiceTotal
 {
 public partial class frmInvoiceTotal : Form
{
    public frmInvoiceTotal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // TODO: declare class variables for array and list here
   decimal[] decArray = new decimal[5];
   int intIndex = 0;


    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       try
        {

            if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Subtotal is a required field.", "Entry Error");
            }
            else
            {
                decimal subtotal = Decimal.Parse(txtSubtotal.Text);
                if (subtotal > 0 && subtotal < 10000)
                {
                    decimal discountPercent = 0m;
                    if (subtotal >= 500)
                        discountPercent = .2m;
                    else if (subtotal >= 250 & subtotal < 500)
                        discountPercent = .15m;
                    else if (subtotal >= 100 & subtotal < 250)
                        discountPercent = .1m;
                    decimal discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
                    decimal invoiceTotal = subtotal - discountAmount;

                    discountAmount = Math.Round(discountAmount, 2);
                    invoiceTotal = Math.Round(invoiceTotal, 2);

                    txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
                    txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString();
                    txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString();

                    for (intIndex = 0; intIndex <= decArray.Length - 1; intIndex++)
                    {
                         decArray[intIndex] = invoiceTotal;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "Subtotal must be greater than 0 and less than 10,000.", 
                        "Entry Error");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Please enter a valid number for the Subtotal field.", 
                "Entry Error");
        }
        txtSubtotal.Focus();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: add code that displays dialog boxes here
     string totalstring = "";
     foreach (decimal value in decArray)
     {
        totalstring += value + "\n";

     }
     MessageBox.Show(totalstring + "\n", "Order Totals");

     this.Close();
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a homework, I can only give you a clue, your loop is currently taking only one `invoiceTotal`, You don't have to use loop at all, When your control enter `btnCalculate_Click` event then after calculating `invoiceTotal`, you can put it to the `decArray` using your class level `intIndex`. Increment the `intIndex` and before entering the value in `decArray` you must check if the `intIndex` is less then `array length`.  Another idea would be to use `List<decimal>` instead of array if you are expecting unknown numbers of input.

Comment: Wow, you guys are awesome! I understand now. Thank you Habib and Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for...loop` sets every index of the array to the total.

```
for (intIndex = 0; intIndex <= decArray.Length - 1; intIndex++)
{
    decArray[intIndex] = invoiceTotal;
}
```

Ask yourself: what is its purpose? You could safely change it to this:

```
decArray[intIndex++] = invoiceTotal;
```

I will leave it up to you to determine how that changes it (since it's homework).